# Hidden parameter for certain users in angular

Tags: angular, parameters

I have a path https:xxxyxxxxxx.com/mypolicy in angular ,This link is applicable for certain users,But when i am giving this url for those users.I need to hide mypolicy parameter ie,
https:xxxyxxxxxx.com is needed when giving to users.(mypolicy as a hidden parameter)only that possible with angular 9.If possible please tell me how it will achieve?

Comment: First easy thing that comes to mind is to route the xxxxx.com to xxxxx.com/mypolicy

Answer (score 0):

Like @Mishna said said, redirect `xxxxx.com to xxxxx.com/mypolicy`.

So instead of routing path use `navigateByUrl` and move user to that url when arriving on `xxxxx.com` (or some other trigger when it's time to navigate) you do:

```js
    this.router.navigateByUrl("/mypolicy", { skipLocationChange: true }).then(() => {
      console.log('user has been navigated to /mypolicy')
    });
```

In the url the user will still see `xxxxx.com` as their location. `skipLocationChange` set to true is what hides change in browser url.

The downside is, you can't route to `xxxxx.com/mypolicy` directly.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer...But here i need to give xxxxx.com to certain domain users  and only for that users need to hide /mypolicy .Is that possible? I mean i need to distinguish different domain users with hidden parameter

Comment: If you don't have login or some other method to distinquish users other than the url their arriving at then I guess your best options still to redirect. E.g if user A arrives to `xxxxx.com/something` user will be redirected to `xxxxx.com//mypolicy` but if user B arrives to `xxxxx.com` he won't be redirected. Essentially you're back to sqare one if users should "share" this secret link. Other form of securing such links is giving the links an unique id which is stored in backend and declared as single time use.